# Given a TTF font file, how do detect if it is an unicode or non-unicode?

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts, non-unicode

I am trying to **convert a txt file** that is **non-unicode to unicode**. **TTF font files are the inputs** along with the txt file, to learn about the source and target.

How do i get information from the **TTF font files** about the conversion that needs to take place?

Comment: Look at the TrueType font's `cmap` table.

Comment: Regardless of the how, why do you think this lets you determine which encoding the file uses? Fonts can support *several* character encodings all in the same file, including "non-unicode" and "unicode" mappings at the same time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use file command, see example bellow:

```
$ file emoji.ttf 
emoji.ttf: TrueType Font data, 11 tables, 1st "OS/2", 14 names, Macintosh, type 1 
string, emojiVersion 1.1emojimj
```